# Get pixel position of particular point upon resizing the image i.e changing the resolution of image

Tags: image-processing

Hi I have image of 1130*2074 resolution I marked a point at pixel 500,430
I have resized it to 1280*1024 how to get changed pixel position i.e what will be the new position of pixel 500,430 I know that basically pixel size was affected but still..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
newX = (500/1130)*1280;
newY = (430/2074)*1024;
```

In general:

```
newX = (currentX/currentWidth)*newWidth
newY = (currentY/currentHeight)*newHeight
```

Comment: thanx will try it out and let you know

Comment: This really worked gr8 thanx for help...Now working on associating latitude longitude to pixel and change according to zoom any review?

Comment: please ask another question for that.

Answer (score 4):

Ratio!

```
new width = (500/1130) * 1280
new height = (430/2074) * 1024
```